# how to insert new line after a specific character in scripts

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have the following (example.txt) file:

```
blue(4) red(8) green(5) yellow(19) brown(60) black(5)
```

how can I achieve in unix the following result?

```
blue(4) 
red(8) 
green(5) 
yellow(19) 
brown(60) 
black(5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following in-line sed script will replace a space with a newline, and should solve your problem.

```
sed -i 's/ /\n/g' example.txt > example_out.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to insert newline after closing brackets, try

```
sed 's/) \?/)\n/g' example.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
xargs -n 1 < example.txt
```

By passing `example.txt` into [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) taking one argument at a time `-n 1`, xargs will place each entry on a separate line.

E.g., to put two entries per line one would simply change the `-n 1` to `-n 2`

The option `-n` is also referred to as `max-args` on the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs).

Answer (score 2):

Pass your data to this sed command, like so:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to achieve something like this and used `sed` command. It can be used to perform functions on streams.

For your requirement, you can use it like this:

```
sed -i 's/ /\n/g' example.txt
```

You can read more about this in [the sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).